# Resetting Visual Studio's Test settings and cache

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, vstest

While working on a C# project in Visual Studio, one of my changes resulted in a number of unit tests (running with VSTest) failing with the following error:

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Edm ..." The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I shelved my changes and rolled back to the latest version of the project, however rolling back doesn't solve the problem. I tried deleting all my local workspace files and pulling the latest code, but it did not resolve the issue. I also tried clearing the NuGet cache on my machine, but it also hasn't had any effect.

The project itself builds and runs correctly, and all the tests pass when run on another developer's environment, so I'm guessing it is an issue with either VSTest or NuGet caching an old version of this particular library. I can't find any sign of caching or settings that would persist this type of problem.

Is there a way to reset the VSTest settings and/or cache? I'm particularly interested if anyone knows why an issue like this would persist even after deleting my local workspace and starting fresh.

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  The Web App builds and runs fine.  I add a unit test project, and copy the web.config to the unit test project's app.config so it will have db connection strings.  The unit test passes.  But next time I attempt to run the web app, the browser displays this error manifest not matching.  Rolling back changes does not fix it.  But rolling back and Getting Latest does.

Answer (score 0):

It can be just bug of Visual Studio or your program (we don't know), so find the point when this happends an try to write that piece of code somelike else. You can also try to restart Visual Studio or PC.